# How To detect Fake mobile number for SMS verification

Tags: php, phone, api, sms

I am facing some issues regarding SMS verification in my website. Suddenly, some transactions are happening using the fake numbers like https://www.receive-sms-online.info

How to detect the number is valid or not because I have checked some APIs, but those also not working like https://numverify.com/.

Comment: Please read http://xyproblem.info and tell us the problem you really have...

Comment: is it a problem that transactions use fake numbers?

Comment: @schroeder corret!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.receive-sms-online.info/ doesn't use fake numbers. The number is valid, and can in fact receive SMS. And that is your entire problem.

They are valid numbers within the national number plan. They are functioning numbers. There is probably no property that is easily visible to you that announces that text messages sent to one of those numbers is publicly accessible.

If you *have* to verify the identify of the person in front of the computer, you need an entirely different framework. Cell phones work because it's slightly harder (but not hard) to get a new number if you need multiple accounts.

In for instance the UK, it takes maximum of ten minutes and a couple of pounds to get a new, anonymous sim card. I habitually have tens of sim cards floating around with perfectly valid numbers, yet you'd be hard pressed to link any of them to me.

In short: use verification SMS to make it slightly harder for users to sign up with multiple accounts and provide fallback communication. You can't use it to totally stop people from having multiple accounts.